# How to identify which dependencies use eval

Tags: javascript, npm, google-chrome-extension, dependencies

I am trying to make a chrome extension but I get an error saying I can't use `eval`. My code doesn't contain `eval` so it has to be in one of my dependencies. What's a quick and easy way to see which dependency or sub-dependency is using `eval`? I removed `node_modules` from the search exclude on VSCode, and I got over 100 results, but it's still unclear which dependency has it because it is under some sub-dependency folders.

Comment: The error message should indicate the file/location. If it doesn't, use the divide-and-conquer approach i.e. remove parts of code until it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for a string in your project. These examples will search for "eval".

Windows Command

```
findstr /S "eval" ./*
```

Unix-like OS Command

```
grep -r "eval" *
```

Comment: What about macOS?

Comment: @abc grep should work for macOS:)

Comment: I ran it and it logged for about 10 seconds - no way to parse it. Is there a command where it can just print out the top level dependencies that contain `eval` in its code or in its dependencies? Basically I just want to know which dependency I need to remove and implement my self

Comment: @abc You can search for "eval(" + only search through the project directory and it will most likely show fewer results.